# Access parent Object in Child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am using rails 2.3.17 and have this relationship setup

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :items, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

Now i need to do a validation on an item,  by accessing `order` object attributes, how can I do this?

When I write

```
validate :checkXYZ

def checkXYZ
  Rails.logger.debug self.order // I AM GETTING NIL
end
```

but when I write

```
before_save :checkXYZ

def checkXYZ
  Rails.logger.debug self.order // I AM ORDER OBJECT
end
```

This is my controller logic

```
@order = @otherObj.orders.create(params[:order])
item = @order.items.create(params[:item])
```

I need to get the order object in validate of item class, how can I do that?

Comment: Please share your controllers logic where you connect your item with order model ?

Comment: Hello Ajay, i have updated the question and added controller logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In before_validate section, the parent(order) is not yet connected to the item object. Hence it'll definitely show nil.

But after the validation is passed & in before_save stage, the order & item are connected hence you are able to access the parent order of the selected item.

You can have below approach to validate your object.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :items, dependent: :delete_all
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :something_missing?
  belongs_to :order

  private 
  def something_missing?  
     your_order = self.order 
      if (add_your_condition_which_is_violated)
        errors[:base] << "Your error message" 
        return false 
      end
       # When you are returning false here, the record won't be saved.
      # And the respective error message you can use to show in the view.
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello Ajay, Thanks for your answer,let me try your solution.voting it up

Comment: Hello Ajay, I am adding validation but its not displaying, can you please tell how do i add error to my order object. Its not saving record but not adding validation either.

I tried by all the below satetment

    self.errors.add_to_base("Error message")

    self.order.errors.add_to_base("Error message")

    self.order.errors.add_to_base("Error message")
    errors.add(:base, "Error message")

but none are working

Comment: see this error message is added to the base key of the items errors. 
after the validation is failed, you can verify that with item.errors.messages[:base]

Comment: Hello Ajay, Yes i checked it and all the error are added to Item Object, how do i add error to Order object

Comment: then instead of putting into errors[:base] try injecting your error message into your  self.order.errors.messages << "Your error messages" .Then your error message will be available for the order object.
order.errors.messages[:base]  this will give you the error message.

Comment: Hello Martin, even if i do that i am bot able to access the errors i set in item model, i need to access it using order.items.first.error

Comment: if you want it on the self/item model then simply keep it errors[:message] << "Your message here", then when you want to show the error message you can use item.errors.messages[:base]. This will give you the error message.

Answer (score 0):

To do this reliably when creating or updating an order you should call the validation on the parent object's (order's) model like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :items, :dependent => :delete_all
    validate :checkXYZ

    private
    def checkXYZ
        Rails.logger.debug self // Here you will have the Order object
        for i in items do
            if (vehicle == 7 and i.distance <= 500) then // vehicle is an attribute of order
                errors.add(:error, "You're driving by car, distance must be larger than 500")
            end
        end
    end
end
```